# Flutter: How to add a TextField or TextFormField programmatically

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have created a form in with formkey and and form data variable as     `Map<String, String> _formdata = {};`
formdata contains  field such as profile data. 
Among those there is a field say Pets, It has two fields name and age.
I want to add a button that will allow user to add more pets. This form should be visible only when clicking the button. User can add multiple pets by clicking this button.

```
class MyPets extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyPetsState createState() => _MyPetsState();
}

class _MyPetsState extends State<MyPets> {
  Map<String, String> _formdata = {};
  var _myPets = List<Widget>();
  int _index = 1;

  void _add() {
    _myPets = List.from(_myPets)
      ..add(Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            leading: Text('Pet $_index : '),
            title: TextField(
              onChanged: (val) => _formdata['pet$_index'] = val,
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Text('Name of Pet $_index : '),
            title: TextField(
              onChanged: (val) {
                _formdata['name$_index'] = val;

              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ));

    setState(() => ++_index);
  }
@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _add();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: ()=>print(_formdata),
        child: Text('Save'),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Add your pets'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Add another'),
            onPressed: _add,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: _myPets,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is when I print _formdata, I am only getting last value.

{pet6: 5, name6: 5}
[image]

Comment: Can you add full code if possible

Comment: Ok I have added full code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me know if it works.

```
class MyPets extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyPetsState createState() => _MyPetsState();
}

class _MyPetsState extends State<MyPets> {
  Map<String, String> _formdata = {};
  var _myPets = List<Widget>();
  int _index = 1;

  void _add() {
    int keyValue = _index;
    _myPets = List.from(_myPets)
      ..add(Column(
        key: Key("${keyValue}"),
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            leading: Text('Pet $_index : '),
            title: TextField(
              onChanged: (val) => _formdata['pet${keyValue - 1}'] = val,
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Text('Name of Pet $_index : '),
            title: TextField(
              onChanged: (val) {
                _formdata['name${keyValue - 1}'] = val;
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ));

    setState(() => ++_index);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _add();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => print(_formdata),
        child: Text('Save'),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Add your pets'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Add another'),
            onPressed: _add,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: _myPets,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work for me. Firstly i click add another few times to create multiple fields. then added data but got output only for last entry ```{pet2: 2, name2: b}``` <br> Also when i edit the first the output still reflects the last change ```{pet2: edit 1, name2: b}```

Comment: I created and added one by one. Let me test it the other way.

Comment: I am able to achieve your answer if i fill in data then add another field fill it and add another. But doesnot work if Multiple fields are added at once. It also doesnt work if edits are made

Comment: I had the same thing and for adding `TextInput` it's working well. But what if we want to remove `TextInput` from the Form then technically it's reducing index value as well as `Widget` item from `List<Widget>`. But UI is not getting an update? I

Comment: I solved my query of removing added `TextInput` from the Form. It'll be done the same way we're adding `Widget` in the `List<Widget>`. 
`_myStudents = List.from(_myStudents)..removeAt(keyValue - 1);`

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Since you didn't share any code, I am giving you an idea how you can do it. Here is the complete code.

```
List<Widget> _children = [];
int _count = 0;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Title"),
      actions: <Widget>[IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: _add)],
    ),
    body: ListView(children: _children),
  );
}

void _add() {
  _children = List.from(_children)
    ..add(TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "This is TextField ${_count}"),
    ));
  setState(() => ++_count);
}
```

Comment: @CopsOnRoad how do i get data from the textfields?

Comment: @Ggriffo You can assign `controller` a `TextEditingController` and use something like `_children[0].controller.text` to fetch the text value.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad What if we want to remove some items from this list? I can update list by using `List.of(_data)..removeAt(position)` & remove specific position item. But what will happen to our `Map<>` data items if we remove it? I could not achieve that.

Comment: @PurvikRana can you please guide me on how to achieve this in flutter-bloc state management.