# how to add TextEditingController and obtain text value from dynamic TextFormField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i want to obtain text value from these dynamic TextFormField

```
class MyPets extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyPetsState createState() => _MyPetsState();
}

class _MyPetsState extends State<MyPets> {
  List<Widget> _children = [];
  int _count = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Title"),
        actions: <Widget>[IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: _add)],
      ),
      body: ListView(children: _children),
    );
  }

  void _add() {
    TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
    controllers.add(controller); //adding the current controller to the list

    for (int i = 0; i < controllers.length; i++) {
      print(
          controllers[i].text); //printing the values to show that it's working
    }

    _children = List.from(_children)
      ..add(
        TextFormField(
          controller: controller,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: "This is TextField $_count",
            icon: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle), onPressed: rem),
          ),
        ),
      );
    setState(() => ++_count);
  }

  rem() {
    setState(() {
      _children.removeAt(_count);
      controllers.removeAt(_count);
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controllers.clear();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

problem is i don't know how to pass TextEditingController to this form-field in flutter
i got above solution from [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55596251/flutter-how-to-add-a-textfield-or-textformfield-programmatically)

basically i want textfields and when i tap a button textfield must increment
and i want the value from each textfield and also i should able to delete the respective fields

please help me 
thank in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can dynamically take the value of all these fields adding the controllers to a list:

```
class _MyPetsState extends State<MyPets> {
  List<Widget> _children = [];
  List<TextEditingController> controllers = [];  //the controllers list
  int _count = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Title"),
        actions: <Widget>[IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: _add)],
      ),
      body: ListView(children: _children),
    );
  }

  void _add() {

    TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
    controllers.add(controller);      //adding the current controller to the list

    for(int i = 0; i < controllers.length; i++){
      print(controllers[i].text);     //printing the values to show that it's working
    }

    _children = List.from(_children)
      ..add(TextFormField(
        controller: controller,
        decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "This is TextField $_count"),
      ));
    setState(() => ++_count);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controllers.clear();
    super.dispose();
  }

}
```

Comment: Glad i can help!

Comment: one more thing is how can i dispose the controllers??

Comment: You can clear the list on dispose, i have editted my answer.

Comment: now the problem is i cant wrap Listview with any widgets like column how to do that

Comment: If you want to wrap a ListView inside a Column, you need to give to the list a fixed height. You can do it wrapping your ListView with a container and setting the height. We can continue the conversation in a chat if you want, but here in comments we can't.

Comment: ty for your response, where we can have conversation??

Comment: Sorry, i created the room but didn't see the **"You'll need 20 reputation to talk here."**

Comment: sorry for that one last thing about this is i want to remove textfields i tried with ```setState() => _children.removeAt(_count);``` but it not worked for me please help me

Comment: Use  **_children = List.from(_children)..removeAt(index);**, or without a index, using **..removeLast()**.

Comment: @LOfG can you please guide me on how to wrap this in bloc state management.

Comment: How to implement enabled and disabeld TextFormField in runtime ?