# In Flutter Unable to change the state of DropDown Menu in ListView

Tags: flutter, listview, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to change the state of DropDown using setState, value is changing but it is not reflecting on UI, it's only reflecting on the new widget when I'm adding a new Widget.

App Function

- Initially, it's a blank screen
- When I click on Add it will add dropdown menu & text field
- Similarly, we can add many. Those widgets will be added to _mypets list
- When I click on save I'm printing an array of lists

How can I change the state?

- This is a Stateful Widget

Please help me to resolve this issue

[image: GIF]

```
class _MyPetNameState extends State<MyPetName> {
  var locationArray = [];
  var _myPets = List<Widget>();
  String sampleData = 'Hello';
  int _index = 1;
  var dataForm;
  String partnerName;

  List<_dropListItem> _weekItems = [
    _dropListItem(1, "Pet Type 1"),
    _dropListItem(2, "Pet Type 2"),
    _dropListItem(3, "Pet Type 3"),
    _dropListItem(3, "Pet Type 4"),
  ];

  List<DropdownMenuItem<_dropListItem>> _weekMenuItems;
  _dropListItem _selectedWeekItem;

  List<DropdownMenuItem<_dropListItem>> buildDropDownMenuItems(List listItems) {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<_dropListItem>> items = List();
    for (_dropListItem listItem in listItems) {
      items.add(
        DropdownMenuItem(
          child: Text(listItem.name),
          value: listItem,
        ),
      );
    }
    return items;
  }

  void _addLocation() {
    Map<String, String> _formData= {};
    int keyValue = _index;
    _myPets = List.from(_myPets)
      ..add(Column(
        key: Key("${keyValue}"),
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: DropdownButton<_dropListItem>(
                value: _selectedWeekItem,
                items: _weekMenuItems,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  _formData['location'] = value.name;
                  setState(() {
                    _weekMenuItems = buildDropDownMenuItems(_weekItems);
                    _selectedWeekItem = value;
                  });
                }),
          ),
          Container(
            child: TextFormField(
              initialValue: '',
              onChanged: (val) {
                _formData['locationType'] = val;
                setState(() {
                  sampleData = val;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ));
    setState(() => ++_index);
    locationArray.add(_formData);
  }


  void _sub(int _deleteIndex){
    setState(() {
      _myPets = List.of(_myPets)..removeAt(_deleteIndex - 1);
      --_index;
    });
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _weekMenuItems = buildDropDownMenuItems(_weekItems);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          print('');
          print(locationArray);
          setState(() {
            dataForm = [];
          });

        },
        child: Text('Save'),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Add your pets'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Add'),
            onPressed: (){
              _addLocation();

            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              children: _myPets,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _dropListItem {
  int value;
  String name;

  _dropListItem(this.value, this.name);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes in your code

This may help you

```
class _MyPetNameState extends State<MyPetName> {
  List<dynamic> radioval = [];
    
  setSelectedRadio(int val, int idx) {
    setState(() {
      radioval[idx]["value"] = val;
    });
  }

  Widget _radioui(int keyValue) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        ButtonBar(
          alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Radio(
              value: 0,
              groupValue: radioval[keyValue]["value"],
              activeColor: Colors.green,
              onChanged: (val) {
                print("Radio $val");
                setSelectedRadio(val, keyValue);
              },
            ),
            Radio(
              value: 1,
              groupValue: radioval[keyValue]["value"],
              activeColor: Colors.blue,
              onChanged: (val) {
                print("Radio $val");
                setSelectedRadio(val, keyValue);
              },
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            radioval.add({"name": "pet1", "value": 0});
          });
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Add your pets'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              children: [for (int i = 0; i < radioval.length; i++) _radioui(i)],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked fine, but I'm following this link 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55596251/flutter-how-to-add-a-textfield-or-textformfield-programmatically' I wanted to have text field & dropdown when click on save button it should get the list of data. I have no idea of doing that. Please guide me